# Internal Server Error when trying to password protect my website

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection, .htpasswd

I am trying to password protect my whole website temporarily, using .htaccess and .htpasswd

The .htaccess file reads:

```
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic

require user xxxxxx
```

When I try to access the website, an ID and password are requested:

```
To view this page, you must log in to area “EnterPassword” on xxxxx.com:80.
```

Then I get this:

**Internal Server Error**

**The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, postmaster@xxxx.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

After I typed the password several times, I still get this. Why?
Is it not finding the page where I want to go after I type the password successfully? (the index.php - should this file be linked somewhere?)

Or is it something else?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in the htaccess?

Comment: Check your server's error logs

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92, [this kind of error logs?](http://i.imgur.com/7y1d43r.png) What exactly am I looking for? No other directives are in the .htaccess